Where to put plain nodejs code in a nuxt 3 app
I want to create a full stack nuxt app app that also has a saperate function that listens to emails with imap, and it uses same functions that the nust server should use, i cannot find where in the nuxt app its the right place for that to go.
the email listener would look something like this
const checkEmails()=>{
//connect to imap and check for new emails
//when done
setTimeout(checkEmails,15*60*1000)
}
checkEmails()


Simply put it anywhere and launch it by node

The server/utils folder is used for shared utility code.
Based on your question you might be able to use Nitro Tasks to run scheduled tasks. It is still experimental, but should be fairly stable.
It would look something like this:
// nuxt.config.ts

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  nitro: {
    experimental: {
      tasks: true,
    },

    scheduledTasks: {
      // Run `email:check` task every 15 minutes
      '*/15 * * * *': ['email:check'],
    },
  },
});

// server/tasks/email/check.ts

export default defineTask({
  meta: {
    name: 'email:check',
    description: 'Check emails',
  },
  async run(_event) {
    console.log('Running email:check task');

    const result = await checkEmails();

    console.log('Done with email:check task');

    return { result };
  },
});

